# Git/Github not letting me push to new branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I created a new branch of a rails app to make some changes to fix some front-end bugs. I don't understand why, but git/github isn't letting me push to that branch. After entering my github password, it just hung there until I cancelled it.

```
% git status
# On branch fefixes
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
% git push origin fefixes
Username for 'https://github.com': {me}
Password for 'https://{me}@github.com':
^C
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here? It's definitely me since github's status is good right now.

Comment: Can you try to take pull from git via git pull to ensure that there is no problem in connection.

Comment: Try running it in verbose mode to see what is happening. `git push -v origin fefixes`

Comment: @Aman Garg I can fetch and tried pulling other repos to make sure it isn't my password/connection. @Vimsha I ran it verbose and here is what i got: `% git push -v origin fefixes
Pushing to https://github.com/colab/repo.git
Username for 'https://github.com':me
Password for 'https://me@github.com':
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
^C`

Comment: what does "git remote -v" tell you? I suspect your remote is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your remote "origin" to ensure the URL looks correct:

`git remote -v`

Next, try listing out the contents of the remote:

`git ls-remote origin`

If all goes well with the steps above, Git is certainly connecting to the GitHub hosted repository. Try the `git push origin fefixex` again.